# How to split data in oracle by yearwise

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select PAY_COMP_AMT,EMPLOYEE_HKEY,trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR') begin_year
     , add_months(trunc(Active_To_Date, 'YEAR'), 12)-12/31/60/60 last_second_year
from table_name;
```

The above query is giving the current year and second last year.Actually, I want to display the rows by year.

Any suggestions will be helpful !

Comment: What do you mean with "display the rows by year"? Can you please post some sample data and needed result to help us understand your need?

Comment: for an employee if the pay period is more than one year then want to display data in separate rows .below is sample data.                                 01-jan-2017 to 31-mar-2019 . In this example i want to display data from 01-jan-2017to 31-dec-2017 in one record ,like wise i want to display data year wise

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to display only the year part of a date column.

So , use `to_char(Active_To_Date,'yyyy')`, and remove the part with `add_months()` function , and implementing an aggregation by `Employee` and `Year` such as `sum`,  you can display your data for each year on seperate rows :

```
select Employee_Hkey, to_char(Active_To_Date,'yyyy') as "Year",
       sum(nvl(Pay_Comp_Amt,0)) as Pay_Comp_Amt
  from table_name
 group by to_char(Active_To_Date,'yyyy'),Employee_Hkey
 order by "Year",Employee_Hkey;
```

Comment: Thank you !! I wanted to display data in different row if the pay period is more than one year.

Comment: Well I edited @Ananymous . You can still use this query in the answer.